# 2 questions about screenplays

Tags: screenwriting

In the slug line, how do I write a time change???

> "7 years later" {then}
>
> INT. HOSPITAL - DAY

Also: how do I write verbal sounds of a character that are unintelligible, etc, be they in the action line usually or do they ever get places in a dialogue line?

> Bathsheba [moans] as she gets to her feet.
>
> Bathsheba laughs hysterically.
>
> Bathsheba snorts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT. HOSPITAL - DAY - 7 YEARS LATER

BATHSHEBA MOANS as she gets to her feet.

BATHSHEBA LAUGHS HYSTERICALLY.

BATHSHEBA SNORTS

```
                         BATHSHEBA
                        (wheezing)
                Please ... stop ... don't
```

RON loosens his grip on her throat, but doesn't get off her.

```
                         BATHSHEBA (CONT'D)
                Why ...
                         (COUGHS twice)
                Why ...
```

BATHSHEBA COUGHS uncontrollably.

```
                            RON
                         (giggles)
                You know why, darlin'.
```